# I can't save with Pil(python) to tga format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to save the image caught with QGraphicsView as the tga format only gets errors and I do not know why

```
grab = self.graphicsView.grab() <-- Catch screen graphicview
pixmap = QPixmap.toImage(grab) <--- Change pixmap to QImage
image = Image.fromqimage(pixmap) <--- Take QImage and do Pil.Image
qtimage = ImageQt(image) 
image.save(qtimage, "image" ,".tga" ) <-- In this place don't work
```

Value Error:

```
TypeError: save() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

but if i change

```
image.save(qtimage, "image" ,".tga" )
```

for

```
image.save(qtimage, "image.tga" )
```

I have another error:

```
image.save(qtimage, "image.tga" )
save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()]
KeyError: 'IMAGE.TGA'
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save), `Image.save` needs only a filename or an open file pointer object:

```
image.save("image.tga")
```

I think you're somehow confusing the library (`PIL.Image`) with your instance `image`, which is already aware of its contents and data. So there's no need to pass in the image again into the save function.

BTW, PIL can also make `Image`s directly from `QPixmap`s. So it should be sufficient to do this, in case you dont need the `QImage` anywhere else:

```
image = Image.fromqpixmap(self.graphicsView.grab())
image.save("image.tga")
```